# using utf-8 in javascript file

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'm trying to use `☰` in external javascript file

```
$('<div />',{
  text: '☰',
......
```

But I couldn't save the file and its saying:

> The document's current encoding can not correctly save all of the characters within the document. You may want to change to UTF-8 or an encoding that supports the special characters in this document.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the file to UTF-8, and then try pasting the character in, again, after it's converted and saved.

Your file could be in one of many, many formats, depending on your editor, but if you're just using a text-editor like Notepad, it's going to cause you problems with things that don't fit happily into ASCII.